# Fire simulation is very weak

Tags: smoke-simulation, fire

[image]My fire simulation on a match tip is producing very weak flames so they aren't visible in the render.
I'm not sure what is going wrong so I just included the entire file.
Plz help, thank you.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Please don't make the question depend on other downloading your file exclusively. Edit your post and add an image of the nodes for the smoke domain. Most likely you just need to increase the values for the emission.

Comment: Sorry, there ya go.

Comment: The emission strength is set to 0

Comment: Sorry, that didn't work :(

Comment: Yes thanks, this was the original question but it wasn't noticed in time for it to stay in the first pages of questions. TY